# Google Places bad data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Some Places Detail provided by Google Places are not correct.
For example if you type Serengeti National Park in the Autocomplete, you have :

```js
{    "predictions" : [
  {
     "description" : "Serengeti National Park, Serengeti, Mara, Tanzania",
     "id" : "08bd9d4d10a2c77c36987c118a638ba8f75fb2f1",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 23,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "reference" : "CkRAAAAAWmw4d0BvC9XVNF73sDnNPiQ841LRJ02RiaLxFonlOJmvmbP01nFpaJVfQVTa1lJScXHCOGtu9P83kUOYAd7f2xIQ_KqR0A_Sbhg8qvEEaIwlEBoU1dU8yFyfIhcZFfRNpdNGpacv6V8",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "Serengeti National Park"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 25,
           "value" : "Serengeti"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 36,
           "value" : "Mara"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 42,
           "value" : "Tanzania"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "establishment", "geocode" ]
  }    ],    "status" : "OK" }
```

Which is ok. Note the description: Serengeti National Park, Serengeti, Mara, Tanzania.
However if you access the Google Places Details you have this:

```js
{
   "debug_info" : [],
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Serengeti",
            "short_name" : "Serengeti",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Mara",
            "short_name" : "Mara",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "TZ",
            "short_name" : "TZ",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "formatted_address" : "Tanzania",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -2.333333,
            "lng" : 34.833333
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "08bd9d4d10a2c77c36987c118a638ba8f75fb2f1",
      "name" : "Serengeti National Park",
...
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

We can see that the formatted address isn't correct, the country name is TZ instead of Tanzania, etc.
I want to pass this data to the Geocoding so I can have a viewport and other geometry data, but for that I need a proper address, like the one given in the predictions.description.
Is there a way to get this data upon selction of this place in the autocomplete?
Or is there another way to get information needed to geocode this place?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you need a adress like in `predictions.description` , why don't you use `predictions.description`

Comment: However, places-details are not provided by google, they are provided by google-users. Feel free to [**suggest more exact details**](http://www.google.com/mapmaker?ui_type=pc&cid=3360063500833208645&src=1&continue=https://plus.google.com/109539907370799505300/about?gl%3DDE%26hl%3Dde-DE&utm_campaign=relatedproducts_pancake&utm_medium=website&utm_source=plus&ved=0CBIQgQY&sa=X&ei=-I9EUqa1FcPdigaGn4HACQ&gl=DE&hl=en&ep=pluspage_hover)

Comment: This is true, however data with type 'geocode' should be controlled by Google. Anyway, it's ok, I'll find a way to use geocoding on the description; it's just less simple than accessing PlacesDetails